# how to display som map with rshiny

Tags: r, rstudio, som

I'm trying to implement som map with rshiny in rstudio , so I have this function :

```
som(data,code , 6,6, init="linear", alpha=c(0.05,0.01), alphaType="inverse",
    neigh="gaussian", topol="hexa", radius=NULL, rlen=1000, err.radius=1,
    inv.alp.c=NULL)
```

I can't understand the meaning of some argument like( code , radius ,rlen) to build the correct som for my data

Comment: I need help !! Any one to answer :(

Comment: Which package are you using? Did you read the help page of the `som` function? You didn't add any data, so noone can run you're code.

Answer (score 1):

I give here description of inputs for you :

`code` is a matrix of initial code vector in the map.

`init` is a character string specifying the initializing method. The following are permitted: "sample" uses a radom sample from the data; "random" uses random draws from N(0,1); "linear" uses the linear grids upon the first two principle components directin.

`alpha` a vector of initial learning rate parameter for the two training phases. Decreases linearly to zero during training.

`alphaType` is a character string specifying learning rate funciton type. Possible choices are linear function ("linear") and inverse-time type function ("inverse").

`neigh` is a character string specifying the neighborhood function type. The following are permitted: "bubble" "gaussian"

`topol` is a character string specifying the topology type when measuring distance in the map. The following are permitted: "hexa" "rect"

`radius` is a vector of initial radius of the training area in som-algorithm for the two training phases. Decreases linearly to one during training.

`rlen` is a vector of running length (number of steps) in the two training phases.